# ibmmq with nodejs - unable to establish connection

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to IBMMQ using my nodejs code, following the instructions from the link https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs. I really don't understand why do we need to install MQ on client machine as per this step here

'It also requires the MQ C client libraries to be installed that you can get from your MQ installation media or from this site.' When I go and the there I see those instructions for installation is for MQ server. But without this MQ C library it is throwing me exception.

I don't really have any local queue, I don't understand why do I need to install all that in my local machine. All I want is that just send messages to the remote queue.

Has anyone used this before, if so how.

Comment: The link "this site" goes to the page `MQC9: IBM MQ V9 Clients`, this is not the MQ server.  The simpliest thing would be to get the Redistributable client since you can just untar this on unix or unzip it on windows.  I have not used the mq-mqi-nodejs that you mention but if it uses the "MQI" this is the C client.

Comment: Aren't they all fixes there? Rather, I looking for a full client install.

Comment: All client packages linked to from that page are full installs.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the README for that package on github includes another link which points at the Redist client packages which are now available more easily. As Josh says, those can be unpacked without neededing a full install process. Of course, if you unpack those in a local directory, you need to remember to run setmqenv as the default locations for discovering the libraries won't work.